# already initialized constant RUBY: heroku rake db:migrate logs show both 1.9.2 and 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

I trying to do a full verification install of Rails 3.1 pre and deploy to heroku.

heroku rake db:migrate fails with already initialized constants RUBy and LN_SUPPORTED
but the error messages indicate that both 1.9.2 and 1.9.1 are both running.

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
rake aborted!
Invalid DATABASE_URL
(erb):9:in `rescue in <main>'
(erb):6:in `<main>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `eval'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `result'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:95:in `database_configuration'
...
...
```

My test_app runs fine with local db

I have no working experience with Heroku yet. I have just pushed files out there.

Comment: Did you every solve this. Can you please paste your code with the following variables: RUBY, LN_SUPPORTED

Comment: You need to post your `gemfile`. I'm sure the problem is in there.

Comment: same problem.. did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Add the required gems to your Gemfile

  - pg (heroku uses postgress)
  - execjs
  - therubyracer
- Make sure you also push your Gemfile.lock file

Comment: This has been fixed. Started all over from with RVM and Gemfile specifying: pg, execjs and therubyracer

Comment: BTW: now therubyracer is no longer required and is actually strongly discouraged by heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem?

This might be what David mentioned: you need to specify these gems for Heroku deployment.
Make sure your *Gemfile and Gemfile.lock is **not** included to your .gitignore file.*

Also you may wanna use Cedar stack on Heroku for. Make sure you used:
`heroku create --stack cedar`
instaed of 
`heroku create`
for a Rails3 app. If it's Rails3.1 then it needs further readings:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Try http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ this book for free walkthrough on Heroku deployment.
You can contact to Heroku's support too.
If you've further question on it please insert your **error, Gemfile, Gemfile.lock**  here (or into Guhub's Gist) and share it.
HTH

Just noticed: you probably don't use RVM and you may have problems with Rake and other gem versions too. Please see RVM: https://rvm.io

Comment: This has been fixed. Started all over from with RVM and Gemfile specifying: pg, execjs and therubyracer