# Heroku Invalid DATABASE_URL when attempting to heroku rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

**Solution**

I'm not sure what the problem was, but destroying the app, recreating it with heroku create --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2, and then doing git push heroku master to the new project fixed the problem.

--

I ran into this problem while trying ot migrate the database on heorku. It runs smoothly on my local machine.

```
(in /app)
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
rake aborted!
Invalid DATABASE_URL
(erb):9:in `rescue in <main>'
(erb):6:in `<main>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `eval'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `result'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:57:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:218:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473871/already-initialized-constant-ruby-heroku-rake-dbmigrate-logs-show-both-1-9-2-an

Comment: I'm trying to execute the ' heroku rake db:migrate ' command. It's returning this error.

Comment: The problem was some weird edge-case on Heroku. Destroying the app and then recreating it fixed the problem. heroku create --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bundle Issue, and I bet you are using different ruby versions. You are probably using 1.8 on local and heroku is using 1.9.

Try This on your local machine:

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle
bundle install --relock
```

Then:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'changed bundle'
git push heroku
```

And then try out your rake task

Comment: I'm using 1.9.2 and Heroku is using stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2. I'm not sure what the problem was, but destroying the app, recreating it with heroku create --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2, and then doing git push heroku master to the new project fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem... "Invalid DATABASE_URL" when trying to run heroku rake db:migrate

I also fixed it by creating a new heroku app.

@codeglot : I tried your suggestion but "bundle install --relock" told me that there was no --relock flag on the bundle install command.

for future reference, I made the mistake when I first created this app of running "heroku create" *before* I ran "git init" (I hadn't initialized git yet). I noticed that I had to manually edit the .git/config file. Heroku received & deployed the app OK, it just then had that subsequent problem described in this ticket. I wonder if this was the reason.